# Instagram API - get images using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append, instagram-api

I made an AJAX function that get the four latest images of my Instagram account. Now I want to make an `append` function that inserts my two first images in a `<div>` called `insta-left` and the two others in a second `<div>` called `insta-right`, but I can't find a solution to split my function:

```js
var token = 'MY_TOKEN', 
    userid = MY_USER_ID,
    num_photos = 4; // number of photos i get

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + userid + '/media/recent',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        access_token: token,
        count: num_photos
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        for (x in data.data) {
            $('.insta-left').append('<img src="' + data.data[x].images.low_resolution.url + '">');
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

If I do it like this all images will be inserted into `insta-left`. How can I split my function to get the two first photos in this `<div>` and the two latest in an other `<div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  $('.insta-left').append(...);
}

for(i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
  $('.insta-right').append(...);
}
```

You can access the the images with `data.data[i]`.

Also, it might be a good idea to run some checks so that it doesn't try to append images that don't exist. Something like,

```
if(typeof data.data[i] !== 'undefined') { ... }
```

Comment: thank you work perfectly i actually will always have more thank 4 images in my account but it's good to know it ;)

Answer (score 3):

How about doing a regular for loop and checking the index?

```
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
    for (i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        if (i < 2) {
            $('.insta-left').append('<img src="' + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url + '">');
        } else {
            $('.insta-right').append('<img src="' + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url + '">')
        }
    }
```

You might also want to think about the case when the Instagram API returns fewer than your requested number of photos.

Comment: I like your solution better than mine. But maybe adding an `else if (i < 4) { ... }` so that it doesn't render more images than it should. And the first `if` statement should actually be `if(i < 2)` since `<=` would render 3 images.

Comment: `if (i <= 1) {…}`  instead of `if (i <= 2) {…}` match for split it in two : 0, 1 and 2, 3

Comment: Good feedback! I changed my answer to reflect these comments.